# How to verify if the protective earth/ground is separated from the neutral wire in an electrical AC installation?

Tags: electrical, safety

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to verify if the protective earth/ground is separated from the neutral wire in an electrical AC installation?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/24737/how-to-verify-if-the-protective-earth-ground-is-separated-from-the-neutral-wire)

It's easy to verify which wire is the phase without relying on wire colors. But I'm not sure if I'm able to determine which wire is the ground and which is the neutral.

I have heard that using a multimeter it will show a higher voltage between the phase and the neutral than between the phase and the ground.

Is that method correct? Is there any other way to determine if the wire colors are correct and the installation was done properly?